A dockerimage to identify a rogue docker container?
I have a VM which is only used to run docker, with a dozen of docker containers.
Once a week, one or more docker container will eat aup all resources (RAM) on that VM requiring me to restart that VM I can't log into that VM anymore
How can I identify that rogue container? As with each restart, all logs are gone, and I'm not going through a dozen of container logs.
Is there a docker image or script (and i'll create that image myself) which can write the docker status into a sstatic file where i can just see the last entries before the crash?

Depending on how you are running your containers you can set a memory limit. Docker swarm makes this particularly easy to manage

You should set the memory limit when you created the docker container: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/
